# adding meta tag on phpbb3 forum script

Tags: php, phpbb3

I am trying to add robot meta tag on phpbb3 forum script. I did added it on overall_header.html file, but it doesn't show up on any pages at all. Is there any other main template file? Please suggest the best way you know to get this done.  Thanks.

Comment: It should be in the overall_header file.

Please link us to a page where there the header file is included and place the header code in this post

Comment: Hi, sorry. Got it working. There was a silly mistake, I forgot to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to stop caching via admin panel to see our custom changes instantly.